# how to show output after executing stored procedure in mssql and php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
$server = 'x.x.x.x\SQLEXPRESS';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'username', 'password');

if (!$link) {

    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
else
{
    echo "Connected!";``
}

$selected = mssql_select_db('dbname', $link)
    or die("Couldn't open database ")

$proc = mssql_init('sp_Index', $link);
$proc_result = mssql_execute($proc);
```

how to show result from $proc_result. my stored procedure is sp_index. i dont know the structure sp_index

Answer (score 0):

What about [mssql_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php)?

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($proc_result)
{
    // Do your thing with $proc['column_name']
}
```